# Laravel hasManyThrough with multiple keys

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to make an application using Laravel 5.5 where I need to get many objects through another except I have 2 key columns to query but can't figure (or find out) how to do it.

Here are my tables:

`[seasons]
id
...`

`[Teams]
id
name
...`

`[fixtures]
id,
season_id,
home_id,
away_id,
...`

From this, I am trying to get a list of teams in the season through the fixtures table using home_id and away_id as my key fields for the team id's.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: 2 team id fields? Cant u just add like a boolean isHome and then use team_id instead of home_id and away_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use a hasManyThrough. treat it like a many to many relationship and use the fixtures table as the pivot.

in Season model:

```php
public function homeTeams(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class, 'fixtures', 'season_id', 'home_id');
}

public function awayTeams(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class, 'fixtures', 'season_id', 'away_id');
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) Using this answer I then went and created a teams() method by merging the 2 collections from the above into one collection so I could loop over one object